# How to disable Unknown property horizontal-align warnings?

Tags: css, visual-studio-code, nativescript

There are some useless warnings I want to disable but I don't know who is giving this warning.
**How to determine which plugin is sending problems?**

### horizontal-align: center is supported by nativescript

[image: Who is giving this error]

```
{
    "resource": "/Login.vue",
    "owner": "_generated_diagnostic_collection_name_#1",
    "code": "unknownProperties",
    "severity": 4,
    "message": "Unknown property: 'horizontal-align'",
    "source": "css",
    "startLineNumber": 191,
    "startColumn": 9,
    "endLineNumber": 191,
    "endColumn": 25
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VS Code doesn't know {N} supports those attributes. But it lets you extend the CSS data set to introduce new attributes.

In your VS Code settings under CSS, you can add Custom Data set. For more details refer [official docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/css#_css-custom-data).

Comment: I didn't understand how to apply it. :-) (https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-css-languageservice/blob/master/docs/customData.md)

Comment: You might want to checkout the [examples here](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-custom-data). If you still have issues, you may have to raise an issue on their repo or start an SO thread specific to the problem.

Comment: FYI, it worked perfectly fine on my end. The warnings went away after I added the attribute in the JSON file. I had to restart the project window though.